# Is it possible to start rxgraph or rxplot via roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

or do I have to execute this tools separately?

Thanks for your effort and help

Bes wishes

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9799/is-it-possible-to-start-rxgraph-or-rxplot-via-roslaunch-.../) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-04-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-04-25**:
What happens if you do `rosdep install rx`?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-04-25**:
Does `rxplot` work on your system when run directly as a command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can execute `rxplot` from a launch file by adding something like this:

```
<node pkg="rxtools" type="rxplot" name="plot_speed"
      args="/odom/twist/twist/linear/x" />
```

I don't know how to execute `rxgraph` like that. Maybe we should open a defect ticket.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-25**:
rxgraph is not a ROS node, as such the arguments roslaunch adds are a problem.  A possible feature request for roslaunch would be to launch non ROS node executables.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi joq,

Thanks for your help! But I have got an error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/eos/ros/rx/rxtools/nodes/rxplot", line 38, in 
import rxtools.rxplot_main
File "/home/eos/ros/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rxplot_main.py", line 47, in 
import rxtools.rxplot
File "/home/eos/ros/rx/rxtools/src/rxtools/rxplot.py", line 62, in 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import 
ImportError: No module named backend_wxagg

when I integrated rxplot into my launch file. What I have to do? I use a Fedora with Python 2.7

Best wishes from Germany

Poseidonius

---

Originally posted by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) with karma: 427 on 2011-04-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2011-12-12**:
Had the same problem today. The missing dependency is called python-matplotlib-wx on Fedora. I didn't find in which rosdep file to add it however....

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-04-25**:
It looks like you're missing some wx system dependencies.